# Is it possible to Pass Empty Parameter to sql server from code behind?

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameter-passing

I have few Parameter in my SQL Query which accepts only ' ' value it will not accept null, so I want to pass '' value as parameter how is that possible, below is my code which I am trying to do

```
param = new SqlParameter("@CodeNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchCriteria.CodeNumber))
  {
     param.Value = SearchCriteria.CodeNumber;
  }
else
  {
    param.Value = DBNull.Value;
    //param.Value = ''; I want to pass something like this
  }
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);


param = new SqlParameter("@LicenseDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
if (SearchCriteria.LicenseDate != null && SearchCriteria.LicenseDate != default(DateTime))
  {
      param.Value = SearchCriteria.LicenseDate;
  }
else
  {
     param.Value = DBNull.Value;
     //param.Value = ''; I want to pass something like this
   }
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

I am not getting any error but in query it is not taking as ' '

Comment: What about passing the string `""`? Of course, that won't work for a `DateTime` parameter.

Comment: DBA has written the query in which I must pass ' ' only

Comment: Yes, but that's an empty string in TSQL. Have you tried passing the empty string in C# as parameter?

Comment: how about empty string and not char `param.Value = "";`

Comment: What about the DateTime it will give the error

Comment: '' != null. also, in sql query, `Field = null` always return false. for skip a conditioning in your query, you must change the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my query and checking if @LicenseDate is null then setting value as empty in SP, and from the code behind i am passing DBNull.Value, which solved my problem for date param

Answer (score 0):

Try passing empty `String` as the parameter when the underlying field is `varchar`. For example, you could do this:

```
param = new SqlParameter("@CodeNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar);
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchCriteria.CodeNumber))
  {
   param.Value = SearchCriteria.CodeNumber;
  } 
 else
  {
   param.Value = String.Empty;    
  }
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

For `DateTime`, SQL Server will treat inserting empty string to a `DateTime` column as inserting the value `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM`, as seen [here](http://rextester.com/IPBYL28777). Therefore, in place of empty string, you could pass in this value of `DateTime` in C#, like so:

```
param = new SqlParameter("@LicenseDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
 if (SearchCriteria.LicenseDate != null && SearchCriteria.LicenseDate != default(DateTime))
  {
   param.Value = SearchCriteria.LicenseDate;
  }
 else
  {
   param.Value = new DateTime(1900,1,1,0,0,0)
   }
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the stored procedure with a default value like the following;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP] 
    @param1 varchar(512),
    @param2 varchar(50) = NULL 
AS
```

Then if you pass the value, the value passed through the param would be taken. It can be skipped from application (c# code) and if skipped the default NULL value would be taken.

So in this case, the @param2 can be skipped when not required from application.

If not null, instead of NULL, you can pass '', like the following

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP] 
    @param1 varchar(512),
    @param2 varchar(50) = ''
AS
BEGIN
```

Comment: What if it shouldn't be `NULL`?

Comment: It is a default value, which can be NULL or an empty string.

Comment: Please ignore my comment since I wrote it before you added the not null case.